# Barrier certificate for simple system

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to prove that for the system $x' \leq -x$, if the system starts with $x \leq 0$, then it is always the case that $x \leq 0$. I'm sure that there are easy ways to prove this, but I'm particularly trying to understand how to prove this using barrier certificates. Barrier certificates are a way of proving reachability theorems. In particular, if one can build a function $V(x)$ such that $V(x) \leq 0$ within the safe region ($x \leq 0$), $V(x) > 0$ outside the safe region ($x > 0$) and has non-positive time derivative $\frac{dV(x)}{dx}x' \leq 0$, then one can conclude that if the system starts in the safe region, it stays in the safe region.

However, I can't build such a function for $x' \leq -x$ with safe region $x \leq 0$. Is there such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x$ is scalar, the following (smooth non-analytic) function may work:

$$ V(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\exp( - \frac{1}{x}), x>0,\\ 
0, x \leq 0,
\end{matrix}\right. $$

It satisfies:

$$ V(x) > 0, x >0, \\
V(x) \leq 0, x \leq 0 $$

While the derivative (exists everywhere) and is:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x } V(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\exp( - \frac{1}{x})\frac{1}{x^2}, x>0,\\ 
0, x \leq 0,
\end{matrix}\right. $$

And so:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x } V(x) \dot{x} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\exp( - \frac{1}{x})\frac{1}{x^2} \dot{x} < 0, x>0,\\ 
0, x \leq 0
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Comment: This is terrific. Does it also work for $V(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2, x>0,\\ 
0, x \leq 0,
\end{matrix}\right. $? More generally, does it work for any function $V(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x), x>0,\\ 
0, x \leq 0,
\end{matrix}\right. $ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: Terrific is a positive thing. I was complimenting you. I was also asking a follow up question to make sure I understood.

Comment: @ValerySaharov, I noticed your construction is only valid for compact sets. Since $V(x)\to0$, as $x\to+\infty$. This solves the problem only locally. How would you propose one that could hold globally?